# RazorEngine: Razor.Parse throws FileNotFoundException every once in a while

Tags: c#, razor, razorengine

I'm having an issue with **RazorEngine** (version **3.4.1.0**).

I'm using `Razor.Parse` method with very simple template in a service that fires up every few minutes, and it works without any issues most of the times, but every now and then it throws this exception on me:

> System.IO.FileNotFoundException: 
>   Could not find file 'C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\Temp\cw3sv4yk.dll'. 
>   File name: 'C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\Temp\cw3sv4yk.dll'

(`cw3sv4yk` is a randomly generated name)

Has anyone bumped into this issue before, and if so - any hints to what the solution would be?

Thanks,
Przemek

EDIT:

I've just noticed that I'm also getting this exception occasionally:

> RazorEngine.Templating.TemplateCompilationException: Unable to compile
>   template. Metadata file
>   'c:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\mscorlib.dll'
>   could not be opened -- 'The process cannot access the file because it
>   is being used by another process.'\n\nOther compilation errors may
>   have occurred. Check the Errors property for more information.

EDIT_2: 
One more exception that's being thrown every now and then:

> System.ArgumentException: Class name is required

Answer (score 0):

Using an overloaded version of `Razor.Parse` method which caches templates solved the issue for us:

```
/// <summary>
/// Parses and returns the result of the specified string template.
/// </summary>
/// <typeparam name="T">The model type.</typeparam>
/// <param name="razorTemplate">The string template.</param>
/// <param name="model">The model instance.</param>
/// <param name="cacheName">The name of the template type in the cache or NULL if no caching is desired.</param>
/// <returns>The string result of the template.</returns>
public static string Parse<T>(string razorTemplate, T model, string cacheName)
```